# How to colour multiple subclasses with similar colours in ggplot lineplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

So, as in the question, I have this dataframe which is also plotted:

```
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(1278)
classes <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "c1", "c2", "c3")
kinds <- c("WWW", "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ", "QQQ", "VVV")
values <- seq(1:100)

vK <- vector()
vC <- vector()
vals <- vector()
for (k in kinds) {
    vK <- append(vK, rep(k, length(classes)))
    vC <- append(vC, classes)
    vals <- append(vals, sample(values, length(classes), replace=T))
}

df <- cbind.data.frame(vC, vK, vals)
colnames(df) <- c("class", "kind", "value")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=kind, y=value, group=class, color=class)) + geom_line()
```

Problem is that each **class** is represented by a different colour which reflect the number, i.e. the *subclass*, in the variable, i.e. a1, a2 etc. What I need is to plot each class with a similar color. In this example we have 3 actual classes, i.e. "a", "b", and "c". Is there a way to colour "a" with sort of different red shades for the *subclasses* 1, 2, 3..., "b" with different blue shades etc...

I tried something like this but it didn't work out since the classes lost the *subclasses*
:

```
df$class <- as.factor(gsub("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0", "", df$class))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=kind, y=value, group=class, color=class)) + geom_line()
```

It means that I need to keep the subclasses.

I am open to different plots too!

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't used `scale_color_manual` to add your own (similar) colors for each subclass? This would make it more clear what you want.

Comment: @Nova well, no. But...will it work even though I have many classes? How will I deal with it? Maybe by generating several palettes, one for each class?

Comment: Why not `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`? That's a pretty busy plot right now.

Comment: @Dunois, actually I have even more subclasses. What do you mean, with  `facet_wrap()`?

Comment: @gabt I'd divide the `class` variable into two parts (so the letters and the numbers), and use the letters to create individual plots within which each dataset will be colored by the respective numbers using `facet_wrap()`. Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/S4a9sjy.png).

Comment: @Dunois, ok but then...do you think it would be easy to compare the differences between the classes? I am expecting the subclasses to behave similarly while the classes differently. Anyway, I'll try it out.

Comment: @gabt that is a subjective issue. IMHO, multiple sparsely populated plots are easier to read than one densely populated plot. If the subclasses are uniform across the classes, then maybe `facet_wrap` with the subclasses instead (it'd end up looking something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/T3iJjc2.png)).

Comment: ok, i'll try it out! thanks for the alternative perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You approach was right. Simply add two additional variables, one for the super-class, one for the subclass. The shading of the subclasses you had in mind cound for example achieved using the `alpha` aesthetic. Try this:

```r
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(1278)
classes <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "c1", "c2", "c3")
kinds <- c("WWW", "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ", "QQQ", "VVV")
values <- seq(1:100)

vK <- vector()
vC <- vector()
vals <- vector()
for (k in kinds) {
  vK <- append(vK, rep(k, length(classes)))
  vC <- append(vC, classes)
  vals <- append(vals, sample(values, length(classes), replace=T))
}

df <- cbind.data.frame(vC, vK, vals)

colnames(df) <- c("class", "kind", "value")

df$class1 <- as.factor(gsub("[0-9]", "", df$class))
df$subclass1 <- as.factor(gsub("[a-z]", "", df$class))
df$subclass1 <- as.numeric(df$subclass1)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=kind, y=value, group=class, color=class1, alpha = subclass1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(.5, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this is very nice. Is there a way to avoid having two legends?

Comment: For sure. What kind of legend do you have in mind? Probably one for showing all 12 lines, if I should guess.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking one for each class, without the need of showing the subclasses. The whole point was to show average differences by plotting all the subclasses.

Comment: In that case simply add `+ guides(alpha = FALSE)`

Comment: how does guide uses the class without specifying it?

Comment: The class, i.e. "a", "b", "c" is taken from the variable "class1" which is mapped on color. Hope I understood you right. BTW. The label of the legend can be changed via labs(), e.g. "+ labs(color = "class").

Comment: maybe I didn't get your answer but...you said  `+guides(alpha=F)` which does not contain any info about using *class1* or *subclass1*. Why did ggplot chose *class1* for the legend?

Comment: (: ggplot2 automatically creates a legend for each aesthetic. In your case one for color (=class1) and one for alpha (=subclass1). `+guides(alpha=F)` simply tells ggplot2 not to show the legend for alpha.

Comment: ah! well, in that case, yes. thank you for the anwers!